# Recommended gasoline types for BMW i3 --- store gasolines to extend the range

Tags: bmw, gasoline, hybrid, electric-vehicle, gasoline-direct-injection

- What are the recommended gasoline types for BMW i3 2014 or BMW i3 2015?

I search online for a while, but I am not sure what are the types of gasoline we can use for BMW i3 2014 or BMW i3 2015?

- Is it possible to buy this gasoline from Walmart or some local shopping malls?

p.s. Is it a good idea to buy the gasoline and store some in the back storage trunk of BMW i3, so in case the cover range (100 Miles) is over, I can still add gasoline to add another few ranges?

Thanks for being friendly and trying to answer my first-ever question!

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Worth you reading : https://www.mybmwi3.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=3328&start=10